# Edit Android lock screen message

Tags: android, lockscreen

I'm making a program which needs to edit lock screen messages. Android OS 4.1 has lock screen settings, one of them is owner information, which allows you to put a string on the lock screen. All I want to do is to know how to edit the owner information text so I can display the appropriate message.

Comment: Also include a bit of code here from your program to show your effort.

Comment: Not possible to achieve unless your app is a system application.